# how to add navigation drawer to different role users like( student, teacher and parent ) after they login?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement Navigation Drawer activity to Student, teacher and parents Activity but it's not working kindly guide me how to add navigation drawer to different roles user after they login.

Comment: You need use <DraweLayout> and inside that use custom views/layouts. Which are childern of  <DraweLayout>.

Comment: Please show your partial code, what you tried already? There are plenty of ways one can achieve this.

Comment: try this one. [link](https://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to custom layouts in `<DrawerLayout>` like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_home" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_nav_main"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">


    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_layout is layout behind the drawer or main layout. And layout_nav_main is use as navigation drawer. So, you can dynamically change layouts or children views in layout_nav_main.